# Using IF statement for combobox

Tags: c#, if-statement, combobox

lets say i got combobox populated with items (items are some numbers for this particular example), and i want to tell C# something like this: `IF` there is some `item` selected in combobox, get that `item` and multiply it by `2`. Is there any way that i can do this?

Comment: And are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: `if (cbItems.SelectedItem == true)` i tried this but it doesn't work, im new to C#.

Comment: What is your combobox populated with?  What are the items? Are the items just strings?

Comment: [ComboBox.SelectedItem Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it was populated by a list of ints. e.g

```
for(int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
{
  myCombobox.Add(index);
}

if (myCombobox.SelectedItem != null)
{
  int value = ((int)myCombobox.SelectedItem) * 2;
}
```

Winforms of course

If they are strings then it would be something ike

```
if (myCombobox.SelectedItem != null)
{
  int value = int.Parse(myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString()) * 2;
}
```